# What legal arguments could the defense use to stop a State racketeering case against an individual based on them being elected president?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, trial

If an individual in the US is indicted on state racketeering charges (e.g. Georgia) and they are later elected as US president, what legal arguments could be made in court by the defense to stop or at least postpone the case while the client is president?

Assume the actual trial has not started yet.

For background, Maggie Haberman's comments: https://youtu.be/xEGOpQtZhCE?t=130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [opinion](https://www.justice.gov/olc/opinion/sitting-president%E2%80%99s-amenability-indictment-and-criminal-prosecution) (initially from 1973 and reaffirmed in 2000) from the [Office of Legal Counsel](https://www.justice.gov/olc) that:

> [federal] indictment or criminal prosecution of a sitting President would unconstitutionally undermine the capacity of the executive branch to perform its constitutionally assigned functions.

This is why special counsel Robert S. Mueller declined to issue a judgment about whether a sitting president had committed crimes. See
[Report On The Investigation Into Russian Interference In The 2016 Presidential Election, Vol. II](https://www.justice.gov/storage/report_volume2.pdf), pp. 1–2.

Footnote 2 from the 2000 OLC opinion notes that a *state* prosecution could present "federalism and comity" concerns, citing *Clinton v. Jones*, [520 U.S. 681](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/520/681/) (1997).

The argument from federalism or comity in relation to state charges has not been fully developed, but the gist is that it would present great practical difficulties for the working of the U.S. federal system if any state could simply indict the sitting president.

Also, what force to give that OLC opinion is not a purely legal consideration (see Ronald Dworkin, *Law's Empire*, Chapter 3: "Jurisprudence Revisited—Grounds and Force of Law"; see also Fred Barbash, "[Justice Department opinions take on the force of law — but are not, in fact, the law](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/justice-department-opinions-take-on-the-force-of-law--but-are-not-in-fact-the-law/2019/05/30/f4efe222-8280-11e9-933d-7501070ee669_story.html)", *Washington Post* (2019)).